# Need to find last day of previous month and previous to previous month

Tags: c#

I have to find the last date of last month(Nov) and a month before that(Oct).
I used the following code:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfLastMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month - 1, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
DateTime endOfLastLastMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month - 2, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

The code works well for today but in the month of Jan the code fails because it supplies month part as 0 and -1.

Please let me know how to do that.
For the month of jan it should say 31 dec and 30 Nov.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way to find the last day of the previous month is to just find the *first* day of the current month (which will always be valid), and then subtract one day. Then do the same thing for the previous month.

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
DateTime endOfPreviousMonth = startOfMonth.AddDays(-1);
DateTime endOfPreviousPreviousMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-1);
```